# Detect index of cell in UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a question related to UICollectionView.
Now, I can make the layout like below picture. Then I want to detect which cell ( index of cell ) that is overlapped with GREEN column when horizontal scroll.
Please help me . Thank so much

[image]

UPDATE

Sorry all of you. The GREEN view is a COLUMN that I want to check overlap with gray cell when scroll

Comment: where is blue row?

Comment: The blue row is a view that I added and adjusted in horizontal center

Comment: You mean the button?

Comment: No, its a normal view. Structure layout: Inside a ViewComtroller, I added View A, Inside View A , I added ViewB , button and CollectionView. So Blue row is ViewB

Comment: I really don't get it. I see a green row, is it that one?

Comment: @Luca a gray row is a cell of CollectionView. And a blue row is a view. So I want to detect the index of gray row when it overlap with blue view.

Comment: @Tamachan Hey. There's no blue row in your picture. Therefore your question is not understandable. Please [edit] and *explain*.

Comment: Wao. Sorry all of guys. Thats my mistake. There's a blue COLUMN ( not a row) . Im so sorry about that.

Comment: @Tamachan The problem is not that it's a column (I could even get it), but the fact that the row is actually green, not blue. Now that we agreed that is that view (the color is not important), wait for an answer by someone

Comment: @EricAya Updated !